# Автокомплит переменных в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

Какой плагин для третьего сублима позволяет дополнять переменные в php/js скриптах? Вроде видел таковой, но забыл как называется.

То есть, если создал переменную, то при дальнейшем ее написании, сублим предлагает в вариантах автокомплита и её в том числе.

**Пример из phpstorm:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это **встроенное поведение**, подбирающее наиболее похожие слова, просто менюшка с предложениями показывается не всегда. В Linux менюшку предложений можно показать явно, нажав <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, а можно попробовать "дополнение вслепую", нажимая <kbd>Tab</kbd>, пока не выпадет нужный вариант. Горячие клавиши можно найти, ища `auto_complete` в файле с *"Key Bindings - Default"* (доступен в палитре команд).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю эту систему, она работает в паре с **подсветкой синтаксиса** и использует её скоупы, чтобы понять, *уместно ли* автодополнение. Можно отдельно указать в настройках селектор, в котором *считать уместным*. Скажем, этот покроет все селекторы, начинающиеся с `source` (исходный код) и `text` (простой текст), то есть **практически всё**:

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
```

...добавлять в файл с настройками пользователя. А чтобы вычислить нужные скоупы, можно установить [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) и посмотреть его вывод в интересующих местах.

Comment: Возможно вы меня неправильно поняли, пример, я создал переменную в js-файле `var dataSend`, дальше в коде пишу `dataSe` и должно подсветить эту переменную, но этого не происходит, но например в php-storm такая возможность есть. http://i.imgur.com/Gf7Ol9I.jpg

Comment: @Jean-Claude вроде то же самое: http://i.imgur.com/wPCs7gF.png

Comment: в общем пришлось искать и нашел плагин -  http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/

Comment: @Jean-Claude и такое есть, он чуть умнее и работает в проекте, а не в пределах файла.