# Всплывающие подсказки Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Предложите литературу (ресурсы), по изучению архитектуры редактора Sublime Text 3.
В частности подключение всплывающих подсказок в области элементов управления?

Answer (score 2):

#### Документация по Sublime Text 3 (на англ. языке):

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/

#### Форум пользователей (на англ. языке):

https://forum.sublimetext.com/

#### Полезно ознакомиться:

[Автокомплит переменных в Sublime Text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510362/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-sublime-text?rq=1)

[Пакетная установка плагинов в Sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437702/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-sublime?rq=1)

Также вот это:

http://rightblog.ru/2781

Видео-инструкция на YouTube (на рус. языке):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZm-Z08jPtI